# How to call state-changing function in web3.py?

Tags: web3.py

I have a simple testing contract:

```
contract TestContract {
    address public owner;
    address public someAddress;

    function TestContract() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        assert(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function setSomeAddress(address _newAddress) onlyOwner public {
        someAddress = _newAddress;
    }
}
```

According to [documentation](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.transact) I should be able to call a state changing function on a contract like this:

```
transact_params = {
    'from': addr_owner,
    'gas': 21000,
    'gas_price': 1,
}
my_contract_instance.transact(transact_params).setSomeAddress(w3.eth.accounts[1])
```

However this throws an exception:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3/contract.py", line 624, in _find_matching_fn_abi
    raise ValueError("No matching functions found")
```

I have tried removing parameters, checking ABI (definition is there),... no avail. What am I doing wrong? How can I call a state changing function with `web3.py`?

Comment: What version of web3.py are you on? Would you add the ABI definition that you're using, and the line creating the contract instance? In general, the approach looks correct.

Comment: I'm on 3.16.2 - but I think I figured it out from source, will post the answer... I see you are one of the developers - thanks for helping out, and thanks for a great library!

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through follow-up, it became clear that the custom contract factory `ConciseContract` was used. That can be specified this way:

```
my_contract_instance = w3.eth.contract(..., ContractFactoryClass=ConciseContract)
```

`ConciseContract` looks up the first function call as a contract method. So this:

```
my_contract_instance.transact(transact_params).setSomeAddress(w3.eth.accounts[1])
```

... attempts to look up the method `transact()` which is not available on the contract. That produces the error:

```
raise ValueError("No matching functions found")
```

---

In general, if you get that error, it means you are trying to interact with a function that is not defined in the ABI. Note that the functions are argument-dependent, so if you try to call the function defined in the ABI as `myfunc(int)` with a string as an argument, the message will be "No matching functions found".

Comment: True - I guess I copied that from somewhere... The problem was that I understood [documentation](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html) as saying that `ConciseContract` was the only (non-abstract) type of `Contract`. So if I understand correctly, my original example should work if I remove `, ContractFactoryClass=ConciseContract`?

Comment: Yes, it looks correct for the default contract. Thanks for flagging the documentation. I see how it could be interpreted that way, so I'll attempt to clarify it.

Comment: I'm not using the custom contract factory `ConciseContract`, and still getting the same error. Can you please extend your answer if you happen to know why?

Comment: @goodvibration I added a bit more general info to the answer. If that doesn't help, I'd recommend asking a new question with background, code, etc.

Comment: [I did, thank you](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34180/calling-a-state-changing-function-via-web3).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** below answer is correct for `ConciseContract`.

The correct syntax (tested in version `13.6.2`) is:

```
my_contract_instance.setSomeAddress(w3.eth.accounts[1], transact=transact_params)
```

Be careful though - if I understand correctly, the `**kwargs` must have zero or one element which is used to specify the type of call (key must be one of `call`, `transact` or `estimateGas`). If `**kwargs` is empty, `call` is used.

`*args` are then passed to contract function.

Comment: This is true, only if you are using the `ConciseContract` contract factory. The syntax in your question was correct for the classic/default contract factory.