# Calling a state-changing function via web3

Tags: solidity, web3.py, state-variable

I am trying to call a function which changes the length of a global storage array.

At first I thought that the problem was related to the array-length changing attempt.

But I have finally come to realize that it is related to the way I am calling it via `web3`.

A similar question is given [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31364/how-to-call-state-changing-function-in-web3-py), but it does not provide the `web3` code which has been used, and so I am unable to make a proper correlation between the answer to it and the problem in my code.

Here is my Python code:

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3 import RPCProvider
from json import loads

eth = Web3(RPCProvider()).eth
abi = open('Test.abi').read()
bin = open('Test.bin').read()
contract = eth.contract(abi=loads(abi),bytecode=bin)
tx_hash  = contract.deploy(transaction={'from':eth.accounts[0]})
address  = eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)['contractAddress']
module   = contract(address).call()

print(module.getLength()) # prints 0
module.setLength(1)
print(module.getLength()) # prints 0
```

And here is my Solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Test {
    uint8[] private arr;

    function Test() public {
    }

    function setLength(uint256 length) public {
        arr.length = length;
    }

    function getLength() public constant returns (uint256) {
        return arr.length;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module` in the question's code will always only make "calls". [If you want to change state, you must make a transaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com//questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call). In web3.py, that looks like:

```
mycontract = contract(address)
mycontract.transact({... your transaction parameters ...}).setLength(1)
```

Then, after waiting for the transaction to be mined, `getLength()` will retrieve the new value.

Comment: I should use `mycontract.call().getLength()` though, right?